# LASSO: Deriving intercept is equal to mean of y

Tags: lasso, regularization

I'm new in the world of mashine learning. My first project is trying to understand the mechanism of ridge/lasso regressions. Im stucked at the point how to derive that the intercept is equal to the mean of y (if x is standardized).
My approach was to partially build the first derivate regarding to the intercept, but I don't get the above result

Comment: Usually, this would be 'by definition'.  Namely to do either ridge or lasso, one scales the data.  This (ahem) means that the mean is removed.  Further consider the case $ \lambda \to \infty$ . Eventually all the regularized coefficients are forced to be zero.  The estimate one wants then is the mean as that is the best zero order estimate of the data.  If you care, I can expand into an answer when I have more time.

Comment: Here's another way to see the result. Standardizing $X$ makes it orthogonal to the constant vector.  Therefore, the least squares estimate of the intercept must be exactly the same as the least squares estimate when $X$ is not included in the regression: that's the mean of $y.$  Since the Lasso doesn't penalize the intercept coefficient, it will have no effect on that result.

Answer (score 0):

We solve the LASSO problem using coordinate descent. That is, given an initial guess $(\beta^{(0)}, \beta^{(0)}) = (\beta^{(0)}_0, \beta^{(0)}_1, \dots, \beta^{(0)}_p)$, we repeatedly update \begin{align*}
\beta_j^{(t+1)} \leftarrow \underset{\beta_j}{\mathrm{argmin}} \frac{1}{2N}\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \beta_0^{(t)} - x_i^{\top}\beta^{(t)})^2 + ||\beta||_1, \quad j \in \{0,1,\dots,p\}
\end{align*}
To update the intercept $\beta_0^{(t+1)}$, we need to solve
\begin{align*}
\underset{\beta_0}{\mathrm{argmin}}\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \beta_0 - x_i^{\top}\beta^{(t)})^2 + ||\beta||_1 
&= \underset{\beta_0}{\mathrm{argmin}}\sum_{i=1}^N \big((y_i - x_i^{\top}\beta^{(t)}) - \beta_0\big)^2
\end{align*}
The solution is given by
\begin{align*}
\beta_0^{(t+1)} &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - x_i^{\top}\beta^{(t)}) \\
&= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\top}\beta^{(t)} &\text{(1)}
\end{align*}
Now, note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\top}\beta^{(t)} = \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\sum_{j=1}^p x_{ij}\beta_j^{(t)}\right)= \sum_{j=1}^p \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}\beta_j^{(t)}\right) = \sum_{j=1}^p \left(\beta_j^{(t)}\sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}\right)
\end{align*}
Thus, if the features $x_1, \dots, x_N$ are standardized beforehand so that $\sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} = 0$, the second term disappears from (1) and we simply have $\beta_0^{(t+1)} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i$.

Note that this solution applies regardless of the value of $\beta^{(t)}$. Hence, for all time steps $t$, the coordinate descent always updates $\beta_0^{(t+1)} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i$.